# How do I plot a dimension vs an other dimension (using dc.js, crossfilter.js) ? a gistup example is included

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

First off, thanks in advance for looking at my question!

So if you click on this gist http://bl.ocks.org/markarios/e95914454a1ef4f7f391 I have a bar chart that shows counts vs ppi for different types of devices (tables, cell phones, computer monitors). But I also have screen brightness data. I would like to plot ppi on the x-axis and brightness (nits) on the y-axis.

My current code is this for the bar chart.

````
dc.barChart("#bar-chart-III") 
    .width(500) ```
    .height(600)
    .dimension(ppi)
    .group(count_by_ppi )
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([ppiExtent[0]-1,ppiExtent[1]+1]));

d3.select("#bar-chart-III").append("text").text("PPI");
````

But where I'm stuck is I have no idea how to define the brightness variable so it can replaces the count_by_ppi variable in the preceding code? Up to this point, I have brightness defined like this.

```
    var brightness = data.dimension(function(d){return d.brightness_nits})
    var count_by_brightness = brightness.group().reduceCount();
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

````
dc.barChart("#bar-chart-III") 
    .width(500) ```
    .height(600)
    .dimension(ppi)
    .group(brightness)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([ppiExtent[0]-1,ppiExtent[1]+1]));
````

Comment: I think your group keys need to be the same as the values returned by your dimension accessor on the barChart. In this case, they are not. So, can you explain what you want to happen on the barChart? Do you want a stacked bar chart by brightness buckets?

Comment: Hi Ethan, ideally I want a scatter plot like this one. http://bl.ocks.org/markarios/raw/95efb90b0a1a61a012ca/ but I think a stacked bar chart by brightness bucks would also work well. However, at this point, I have some pain points due to my knowledge gaps in group keys. So I'm going to be studying those today and try this again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create several groups with the same keys as your dimension (ppi) - one group for each brightness bucket you want. Then you'll want to use the dc.js .stack() method to add those groups on to your stacked bar chart (use .group() once and .stack() several times, IIRC).

The stack() method is documented under the stack mixin:
https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#stack-mixin

It seems like this sort of 'group of buckets' is something that is needed fairly often, so I'm going to try to create a helper for it in the [Reductio](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio) project, but I haven't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: I just updated the Reductio project with an aggregation that has the same properties as the d3.layout.histogram layout. Specifically, you can define the value you want to create a histogram for and the thresholds of the histogram bins you want to use. I believe you can then use these bins as dc.js 'stacks' with accessors like function (group) { return group.histogram[0]; }. Just increment the index in the group.histogram array for each stack. Not very well tested though, so let me know if you try it and have issues :-)

Comment: Thanks very much Ethan. This is still a little beyond my head. So I'm going to studying crossfilter all week. Currently watching a bay area d3 user group video on crossfilter to try to eliminate my blind spots. I did check out your Reductio histogram bin work. Once I get done with the video I'll check it out. Thanks again, Mark.

Comment: I'm still studying reductio. I'm trying to figure out how to use it with dc.js. But so far it looks pretty good and I think it's going to save me a lot of time. Thank you for writing it.